# Why neither browser will save BofA password or explain way?

Tags: firefox

On fresh install of Ubuntu 19.10, using both Firefox 73.0 and Chrome 80.0.3987.100.

I go to bankofamerica.com and login.  The browser pops a dialog asking if I want to save my password, I click yes.  However, when I go and search saved passwords it's not there, and when I logout and attempt to login again, the password isn't recalled.  There are no indications of errors or failures.

It didn't use to be this way before I did a fresh OS reinstall last week.  (Was on older Ubuntu before, something between 18.04 and 19.04.)

Comment: Have you set a master password on browser?  Browser password managers are usually considered not as safe as third party apps/programs.

Answer (score 2):

Your browsers are complying with a site requirement not to save the password.  I've seen this for years, on Bank of America, Wachovia, and its buyout partner, Wells Fargo; I presume it's standard for any banking site.

The page code for the login page can include something along the lines of "save-password-okay = NO" and your browser will comply.  In fact, I'm used to my browser (SeaMonkey, effectively Firefox skinned to look like the old Netscape Navigator or Netscape Web Suite) not even popping up the dialog to save the password, though it will save the user name.

There are installable password managers that *can* save the password for sites that forbid it, but standards compliant browsers will not do so on their own.

Comment: But that still doesn't explain the behavior (design decision?) of asking me if I want it to save the password, but then silently choosing not doing do so without alerting me in any way.

Comment: Given that Firefox is currently emulating the Chrome interface, it's tempting to suggest this is a bug that carried over from one to the other.  One of the reasons I use SeaMonkey is that I dislike the Chrome interface.